# How do I make find out if an array contains a certain value?

Tags: php

I would like to find out if an array as a certain (number in this example) and print.

If value 0 in array $a contains 1.10 print out yes.

```
$a = array(1.10, 12.4, 1.13);

if (in_array([0] == '1.10')) {
    echo "Yes";
}
```

Comment: Use `array_search()`.

Comment: Why is everyone using `in_array` in their answers? He only wants to know if element 0 contains 1.10, not if it's anywhere in the array.

Comment: @Michael Sórm do you want to know if it is at a specific location, or just to know if it exists in the array?

Comment: The question reads "if an array contains a certain value", so I take it as "in any position".

Answer (score 2):

No searching is required, just access the element using ordinary array indexing.

```
if ($a[0] == 1.10) {
    echo "Yes";
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually answering the OP's question. *"If value 0 in array $a contains 1.10 print out yes."*

Comment: And don't forget that floating point comparison is tricky because storing floating points in binary format is not exact.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
<?php
$a = array(1.10, 12.4, 1.13);
if($a[0] == "1.10"){
 echo "Yes";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a minor adjustment in your [in_array PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) usage:

```
<?php
$a = array(1.10, 12.4, 1.13);

if (in_array(1.10, $a)) {
    echo "Yes";
}
```

#### Output:

```
Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(1.10, 12.4, 1.13);

if (array_search('1.10', $a) === TRUE) {
    echo "Yes";
}
```

Comment: While this answers the question, please include explanation of what the code does and why it works.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

which is used in the following manner:

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
?>
```

If it is in the data, `$key` is given the corresponding value of the element that contains the data you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn proper syntax. Try:

```
if ( in_array('1.10', $a) ) {
    echo "Yes";
}


//syntax
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
```

Function Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

1- if you know the index then you can simply do:

```
if($array[$index] == '1.10'){

}
```

2- if you want to search for a value if exists in the array:

```
if(in_array("1.10", $array)){

}
```

3- if you want to find key for a given value:

```
   $key = array_search("1.10", $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aray_search
it returns the corresponding key if successful.

```
$a = array(1.10, 12.4, 1.13);

if (array_search('1.10',$a) !== false) {
    echo "Yes";
}
```

output:

> Yes

you can speed up the function by turning on the strict mode:

it returns the corresponding key if successful.

```
$a = array(1.10, 12.4, 1.13);

if (array_search('1.10',$a,true) !== false) {
    echo "Yes";
}
```

output:

> Yes

Comment: Please add explanation as to why the code works and what it does.

Answer (score 0):

To just search the first element in the array:

```
if ($a[0] == "1.10") { echo "Yes"; }
```

Or to search the whole array:

```
if (in_array("1.10", $a)) { echo "Yes"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<?php
$a = array(1.10, 12.4, 1.13);

$isExists = in_array(1.10, $a) ? "Exists" : "Not Exists";

echo $isExists;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<?php
$a = array(1.10, 12.4, 1.13);
echo ($a[0] == "1.10")? "Yes" :"";
?>
```